# if $\sum_{n=0}^\infty na_n$ converges, does $\sum_{n=0}^\infty na_{n+1}$ converge?

Tags: calculus, summation

If the sum :$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty n\, a_n$$ converges does it mean that : $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty n\, a_{n+1}$$ converges too?

(Note that $a_n$ can be negative)

Comment: I think that if $\;a_n\;$ is all the time non-negative or all the time non-positive the claim is true and it is easy to show. Thus, the problem is when the general term sequence doesn't have a definite sign.

Comment: Hint: Note that $\sum_{n=0}^\infty n a_{n+1} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty (n-1) a_n = \ldots$

Comment: Note: $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty n\, a_{n+1}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty (n-1)\, a_{n}=\underbrace{\sum_{n=1}^\infty n\, a_{n}}_{\text{converges}} - \sum_{n=1}^\infty \, a_{n}$$

Comment: so, basically, this boils down to "can you have $\sum a_n$ divergent while $\sum na_n$ converges?"

Comment: @ClementC. I think so...and the last step in John Doe's comment is true **if** $\;\sum a_n\;$ converges, otherwise that can't be done, imo.

Comment: @DonAntonio Replacing the upper bound $\infty$ in the sums by $N$ in what he did, you do get the fact that the OP's question and my last comment are equivalent. Can't think of a counterexample, though.

Comment: @ClementC. Me neither...so far. Intuitively it is "very clear", though...but, of course, intuition can be a nasty thing some times

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that $\sum_{n\geq 1}n a_n$ is convergent, we want to show that $\sum_{n\geq 1}(n-1)a_n$ is convergent as well, so it is enough to show that in the given hypothesis $\sum_{n\geq 1}a_n$ is convergent.

Let $A_n = 1 a_1 + 2 a_2 + \ldots + n a_n$. By summation by parts:

$$ \sum_{n=1}^{N} a_n = \sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{1}{n}(na_n) = \frac{A_N}{N}+ \sum_{n=1}^{N-1} \frac{A_n}{n(n+1)} $$
and $A_n\to C$ as $n\to +\infty$, hence $\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{A_n}{n(n+1)}$ is an absolutely convergent series and $\sum_{n\geq 1}a_n$ is convergent (at least conditionally).

Answer (score 8):

Notice that it suffices to prove that $\sum _{n} a_n$ converges since

$\sum_{n} (n+1)a_n = \sum_{n}na_n + \sum_{n}a_n$

This is an application of Dirichlet's test, 
$$\sum_{n}(na_n)\cdot \frac{1}{n}$$

Comment: I think this nails it exactly on the top of the head! +1 Yet I think it is *Abel's Test* as we have a convergent series and a bounded monotone sequence and etc.

Comment: That is to say, summation by parts

Comment: The sum on the left should be $\sum_{n=2} (n-1)a_n$ although that does not really change the solution.

Answer (score 2):

Abel's convergence test: If $\sum_n c_n$ converges and $(d_n)_n$ is a bounded monotone sequence then $\sum_nc_nd_n$ converges. Apply this with $c_n=na_n$ and $d_n=(n-1)/n.$

Comment: [Dirichlet's test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_test) and [Abel's test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_test) are really the same thing

Comment: I can't see this post adds anything to the above given answer more than 11 minutes ago...